# Accessing boolean values within objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

Hi I am a beginner learning javascript (this is my first question) and have spent hours trying to solve the below. Can't find a answer online, so any help would be so much appreciated :)

I have a list of books which are objects within an array. The properties are the name (value is a string) and whether or not the book is Best-Selling (value is a boolean). See below

```
const books = [
{ name: 'Book 1',
bestSelling: true,},
{ name: 'Book 2',
bestSelling: false,},
{ name: 'Book 3',
bestSelling: true,},
];
```

What I am trying to do is access the bestSelling values from the array. Firstly how would I do this.

Secondly, how would I write a function which if there was *at least* one book which wasn't best selling would return false overall, and if *every* item within the array was best-selling would return true?

I have come up with the following but it does not seem to work:

```
let won = 0
for (let i = 0; i> books.length; i++) {
if (books[I].bestSeller === false) {
return false;
}
} return true;
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Also, in `for (let i = 0; i > books.length; i++) {`, it should be `<`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Johnny, and letting me know what to research! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Enamul I added an answer. Hope that will work as per your requirement. Please let me know if any further help required.

Answer (score 0):

Use `books[index].bestSelling` to access the booleans and, you can use `Array#every()` to check if all books are best selling - return `true` - otherwise return `false`.

```js
const books = [
    { name: 'Book 1', bestSelling: true},
    { name: 'Book 2', bestSelling: false},
    { name: 'Book 3', bestSelling: true}
];

//accessing booleans books[i].bestSelling eg
console.log( books[0].bestSelling );

//function to return true only if all books are best selling
function isBestSeller(books) {
    return books.every(book => book.bestSelling);
}

console.log( isBestSeller( books ) );
```

**NOTE:**

`return books.every(book => book.bestSelling);` is equivalent to:

```
return books.every(function(book) {
    return book.bestSelling;
});
```

And the whole function can be re-written as:

```
const isBestSeller = books => books.every(book => book.bestSelling);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to do is access the bestSelling values from the array. Firstly how would I do this.

You can achieve that via using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```js
const books = [
{ name: 'Book 1',
bestSelling: true,},
{ name: 'Book 2',
bestSelling: false,},
{ name: 'Book 3',
bestSelling: true,},
];

const bestSellingBooks = books.filter((obj) => obj.bestSelling);

console.log(bestSellingBooks);
```

> Secondly, how would I write a function which if there was at least one book which wasn't best selling would return false overall, and if every item within the array was best-selling would return true ?

You can achieve this by using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```js
const books = [
{ name: 'Book 1',
bestSelling: true,},
{ name: 'Book 2',
bestSelling: false,},
{ name: 'Book 3',
bestSelling: true,},
];

const bestSellingBooks = books.some((obj) => !obj.bestSelling);

console.log(bestSellingBooks ? false : true);
```